# Treating multiple columns as a single entity with Google Sheets QUERY function

Tags: google-sheets, group-by, google-query-language, google-sheets-query, sql-limit

The code below inside the `QUERY()` spreadsheet function doesn't seem to work as expected!

```
=QUERY(...., "Select E, I, count(H) group by E, I order by count(H) desc limit 10")
```

Result: Overall Top 10 rows based on `Count(H)`

Expected/Looking for: Top 10 rows "for each group" (E,I)

Any ideas/suggestions would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Just to be sure I understand well, you don't want to `count` H, you just want to sort by the number in column H? (since you say you want the top 10 of each group, I assume you don't want to group the value of each group)

Comment: That's correct. Its like finding top 10 Students from each Class and for each Subject. Thanks so much for your advice in advance!

Comment: Thank you Rubèn for editing the code!

Comment: ...Try `=SORTN()`